# Как вывести количество записей из таблицы с уникальными значениями столбца

Tags: sql, select, count

Есть таблица payments. У нее есть столбец users_id, значения в котором повторяются. Надо посчитать, сколько разных users_id встречается в этом столбце.
Вот код, но что-то ничего не выводит:

```
$query = "SELECT count (DISTINCT users_id) FROM payments";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: *ничего не выводит* Запрос верный, если не считать лишнего пробела между именем функции и скобкой.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. 
в коде вопроса пробел между count и ( лишний. Конструкция count(DISTINCT users_id) работает.

```
select count(distinct rev), count(distinct content) from docs;
```

Вариант 2. Сгруппировать и посчитать количество записей в сгруппированном результате:

```
select count(*) as CONTENT_COUNT from 
    (select content from docs group by content) a;
```

Вариант 3: То же самое, но вложенный запрос группирует с помощью distinct

```
select count(*) as CONTENT_COUNT from 
    (select distinct content from docs) a;
```

Пример можно попробовать в [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfb80/1) с кодом схемы

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
      `id` int(6) unsigned not null,
      `rev` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `rev`, `content`) VALUES
      ('1', '1', 'A'),
      ('2', '1', 'B'),
      ('3', '2', 'B'),
      ('4', '3', 'B');
```

Comment: не работает все равно

Comment: Добавил второй вариант и примеры.

Comment: спасибо, разобрался!